# discussion about @RequestParam and @RequestBody

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have a class:

```
public class user{
    private String id;

    private MultiPartFile file;
    **Getters And Setters**
}
```

And in the Controller:

```
@PostMapping(value="/upload)
public void upload(User user){
}
```

In the front end I post data with form-data.I can get the user object.
But when I add `@RequestBody` and `@RequestParam`,it can't works.

in my opinion，`@RequestParam` is used to binding parameter to simple class . when I use `@RequestBody` ,spring will find `HttpMessageConverter` to convert `http request body` to class.But I'm not sure about that.Does anyone can explain to me?

Answer (score 1):

So, I believe we are talking about `org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile`, which is to be used together with `@RequestParam` variable. The mechanism is somewhat special in this case.

I had a similar problem, and what I ended up using was `org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver`. From frontend I've constructed multipart request with two parts, in your scenario it could be `user` (containing just JSON data) and `file` (containing the file itself), e.g.:

```
@PostMapping(value="/upload")
public void upload(@RequestParam("user") User user, @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file){
    ...
}
```

But then, you need to configure custom serialization of the `User` part, which can be done using `org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver`. You can configure it using bean config like this:

```
@Configuration
public class MappingConfig {

    @Order(Integer.MIN_VALUE)
    @Bean(name = "multipartResolver")
    public CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
        return new CommonsMultipartResolver();
    }

    @Bean
    public Converter<String, User> stringToUser() {
        return new Converter<String, User>() {
            @Override
            public User convert(String jsonString) {
                return new Gson().fromJson(jsonString, User.class);
            }
        };
    }
...
}
```

Also, as you can see I am using `Gson` manually, I couldn't find a better way how to do it. Also, it doesn't play with Java 8 lambdas, so it cannot be shortened (because of explicit types are needed for it to work).

I hope that this will at least points you to a right path.

Comment: Thanks for your apply. It seems that you use `Converter` to convert `httpRequest` to `Object`.I tried but did not work. My application uses `RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver` to do that thing.when I remove `@RequestParam` . How spring works?

Comment: How it did not work? There are multiple approaches to do the same thing, so maybe you need to choose one path. I am not exactly sure if I understood the original question, but the code I posted above work for me and for the scenario I described.

Comment: I added it to my spring boot application. But it didn't took any effect.when my application   analysis the `@RequestParam user` ,it use `RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver`.So I don't know how to config the bean `converter`.

Comment: What do you mean it didn't make any effect? Is the configuration not registered? If you debug the bean creation does it not get called?

Comment: I added `@Configuration`.And I checked the `bean` had beed created. but spring doesn't use this converter to transfer the parameter.

Comment: How does your `Converter` bean for the `User` look like? Are you using `Gson` as well?

Comment: Thank you for your patience.Just like your sample.I add `Gson`.I had never used it before.Do I need other configurations？

Comment: Well I don't have anything else configured, maybe you have something that overrides this configuration?